# Adding Leading Zeros t in Google App Script, Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I have a master sheet and I am copying the values from there and putting it in a new tab. But when I display the number in the new tab it is getting rid of the leading zeros. For Example: in my master sheet I have 00734 and I copy it to the new tab and it's showing as 734.

Here is the code I am using it to copy the values:

```
 var values = active.getRange(startAt, 1,numRowsToCount,16 ).getValues();
```

This is where is put the values into the new tab:

```
 active.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values).setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontFamily("Calibri").setFontSize(11); 
 active.getRange(1,12, values.length,1).setValue(values[0][0]).setNumberFormat("00####");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
var values = active.getRange(startAt, 1,numRowsToCount,16 ).getValues();
```

with:

```
var values = active.getRange(startAt, 1,numRowsToCount,16 ).getDisplayValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

## I'm not sure that I believe that:

Here's my test code:

```
function getRealValues(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var end="is near";
}
```

Here's my debug results and spreadsheet data in one image:

[image]

I played around with it a bit and found that if it's plain text they are both the same but if you use a numberformat to create the leading zeroes then there is a difference between the two.

New code:

```
function getRealValues(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  rg.setNumberFormat('00#');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var end="is near";
}
```

Here's the new debug and spreadsheet image:

[image]

- [Number Format Tokens](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens)

## I guess I'm a believer now